# Scripting if-else nesting to select a string type from a list, as python function argument

Tags: python, string, function, if-statement, exception

I have a `python` function defined as such:

```
def fun(name=None):
    data = [['tom'], ['nick'], ['juli']]
    
    name0 = data[0]  # tom
    name1 = data[1]  # nick
    name2 = data[2]  # juli
    if name is not None:
        if name=='tom':
            Name=name0
        if name=='nick':
            Name=name1
        if name=='juli':
            Name=name2

    if name is None:
        print('Reading all the names')
        Name=data
    else:
        raise Exception('arguments cannot be empty. Either pass one single name or None')
    return Name
```

This is a simplified represenation of my actual script. For my workflow I need to call such a function for a specific `string type` argument `Name` that is being stored as a list `data`. Now when I call this function for `tom`:

```
fun('tom')
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 26
     23         raise Exception('arguments cannot be empty. Either pass one single name or None')
     24     return Name
---> 26 fun('tom')

Cell In[28], line 23, in fun(name)
     21     Name=data
     22 else:
---> 23     raise Exception('arguments cannot be empty. Either pass one single name or None')
     24 return Name

Exception: arguments cannot be empty. Either pass one single name or None
```

As you can see the `if` tree is being skipped and either working with `None` or the `else` part is being executed. Why this function is skipping the `if` tree. Because in one of my earlier script such a logic worked. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ```data[0] != 'tom'```, ```data[0] = ['tom']```  Also,  you use a ```name``` kwarg  in your ```fun()``` so your call should be ```fun(name='tom')```

Comment: Given you call `fun('tom')` that means `name = 'tom'` which means `name is None` evaluates to `False` what else do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's an issue with your code. The `raise Exception` block is being triggered even when `name` is provided. This might be due to the indentation of the block. Try adjusting the indentation like this:

```py
def fun(name=None):
    data = [['tom'], ['nick'], ['juli']]
    
    name0 = data[0]  # tom
    name1 = data[1]  # nick
    name2 = data[2]  # juli
    if name is not None:
        if name == 'tom':
            Name = name0
        elif name == 'nick':
            Name = name1
        elif name == 'juli':
            Name = name2
    else:
        print('Reading all the names')
        Name = data

    return Name
```

This should resolve the error. Additionally, I replaced the separate `if` statements for each name with `elif` to make the code more concise.

Comment: This code is broken. If *name* is not None and is neither "tom", "nick" nor "juli" then an UnboundLocalError will occur

Answer (score 1):

Your code is unnecessarily complex.

```
def fun(name=None):
    names = ["tom", "nick", "juli"]
    if name is None:
        return [[name] for name in names]
    if name in names:
        return [name]
    raise Exception(f"{name} is not in list of known names")

print(fun("nick"))
print(fun())
print(fun("banana"))
```

**Output:**

```
['nick']
[['tom'], ['nick'], ['juli']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/CtrlZ/Python/Jan05.py", line 41, in <module>
    print(fun("banana"))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/CtrlZ/Python/Jan05.py", line 37, in fun
    raise Exception(f"{name} is not in list of known names")
Exception: banana is not in list of known names
```

Using this pattern makes it easy to add names to the *names* list without writing additional if/else code

Comment: In this case, the error message makes no sense, since name is not empty, but that's what the exception says. This is also why I made my code as it is.

Comment: @Cow I agree that the exception message makes no sense. However, the intention was to replicate OP's functionality. I'll change it to something more meaningful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def fun(name=None):
    if not name:
        raise Exception('arguments cannot be empty. Either pass one single name or None')
    data = [['tom'], ['nick'], ['juli']]
    if name=='tom':
        return data[0]
    if name=='nick':
        return data[1]
    if name=='juli':
        return data[2]
    print('Reading all the names')
    return data

print(fun('tom'))
```

Result:

```
['tom']
```

Comment: First you have `if name is not None`, then you have `elif name is None` and then an `else`. The `else` will never run since either of the two conditions will end up being `True`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat You're absolutely right

Comment: This has different functionality to OP's original code (when *name* is None)

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple dictionary with method get. In latest python versions, You can use the optional argument to return prepared response if You try to ask for nonfind key value.

```
def check_names(name: str) -> str:
    data = {'tom': 'name0', 'nick': 'name1', 'juli': 'name2'}

    response = data.get(name, 'Reading all the names')
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(check_names('nick'))
    print(check_names('Olaf'))
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood OP's question

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).